# Why are Linkedin not picking up my Open Graph image meta tag?

Tags: html, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, socialshare

**Linkedin not picking up on Open Grap Tags**

When I try sharing our blogposts on Linkedin, it is not picking up the image defined in our og:image meta tag - and I simply cant figure out why.

**Blog post**

Here's a link to the blog post that I've tried to share: https://sleeknote.com/blog/customer-loyalty-programs

**Example**

Here's an example of how Linked in picks up the fist image the crawler encounters (and not the one defined in the og:image tag) and how the image then gets blurry because of the bad dimensions: http://take.ms/IFYto

For test purposes I've changed the color of the watch rim in the image from brown to blue, only in the image expected to be shared on Linkedin (meaning the image referred to in og:image tag).

I've read Linkedin's own documentation and cannot find any reasons why they shouldn't be able to pick up on the Open Graph tags.

Answer (score 1):

We've been having a similar issue. Our problem was the image file size being over 5MB. Here's [LinkedIn's policy](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en) on og:image files:

- Max file size: 5 MB
- Minimum image dimensions: 1200 (w) x 627 (h)pixels
- Recommended ratio: 1.91:1

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for the people who tried all the methods described in the above answers and still got no luck !!

> I had this scenario and I fixed it by renaming the og:image.

I believe image with long name can trick the linkdin to prevent the image from **scraping**.

before the tag was

```
<meta property="og:image" name="image" content="images/meta-this-is-a-very-long-name.jpg">
```

I fixed this issue by renaming it to a smaller name.

```
<meta property="og:image" name="image" content="images/meta-image.jpg">
```

voila.. it worked !!

you can check whether the image is updated by going to this link and enter your site address
https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this and still had no luck. My images are served dynamically, I have met the dimension requirements, the filesize requirements, the markup standards. Everything works great on X as well as Meta but no cigar on LinkedIn so far.

Answer (score 0):

For my part the problem came from the `.htaccess` with a rule against certain badbot:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Link [OR]`

Cheers !

Answer (score -3):

I thinks this post can help you: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin#

Wait 7 days and said me after..